# Get week of year (the first day of week is Sunday) could not return week 53

Tags: perl, posix

```
use strict;
use Time::Local;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date = '12/31/1899';
my ($month, $day, $year) = split '/', $date;

my $epoch = timelocal( 0, 0, 0, $day, $month - 1, $year - 1900 );
my $week  = strftime( "%U", localtime( $epoch ) );
```

printf "Date: %s Week: %s\n", $date, $week;

=> Date: 12/31/1899 Week: 53

However when $date = '12/30/1900', it return week 52 not week 53.

Could you please help me to point out the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Re "*However when $date = '12/30/1900', it return week 52 not week 53.*", As it should. [calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1900) "%U The week number of the current year as a decimal number, range 00 to 53, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of week 01."

Comment: @ikegami Could you please suggest me the solution for this one?

Comment: You have yet to identify a problem

Comment: yes, I could not identify the problem. As I understand, 12/30/1900 is Sunday, so it will be the start of new week. It should be 53.

Comment: It is the start of a new week, but it's the start of week 52.

Comment: 1900 starts on a monday; week 1 doesn't start until 1900-01-07.  and week 52 starts on 1900-12-30; not every year has a week 0 or a week 53

Answer (score 6):

> `%U`
>
> The week number of the current year as a decimal number, range 00 to 53, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of week 01.  See also `%V` and `%W`.

By that definition, 1900-12-30 is part of week 52.

You can verify this yourself using a [calendar of 1900](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1900).

- Week 0 of 1900: Mon, Jan 1, 1900 to Sat, Jan 6, 1900
- Week 1 of 1900: Sun, Jan 7, 1900 to Sat, Jan 13, 1900
- ...
- Week 51 of 1900: Sun, Dec 23, 1900 to Sat, Dec 29, 1900
- Week 52 of 1900: Sun, Dec 30, 1900 to Mon, Dec 31, 1900

---

That said, it's a fluke that you are getting the right answer (`52`). You are passing `0` (`$year - 1900`) as the last argument to `timelocal`, and that refers to the year 2000, not the year 1900.

This explains why you were getting `53` for `12/31/1900`. While 1900-12-31 is in week 52, 2000-12-31 starts week 53.

To fix this, replace

```
timelocal( 0, 0, 0, $day, $month - 1, $year - 1900 )
```

with

```
timelocal( 0, 0, 0, $day, $month - 1, $year )
```

Comment: You can see 12/31/1900 (Mon, Dec 31) is not part of week 52. It is week 53. You can check with above code. It is strange.

Comment: Thanks for your info. But our date is later than 1970-00-00T00:00:00Z.

Comment: @hhy NOT all the years have 53 weeks, A year has 52 weeks and some remainder. This remainder is carried forward. So in the case above, you get `1899,1905,1911,1916,1922,1928,1933` etc etc have 53 weeks. All the rest in between have 52 weeks. This is not a bug

Comment: Updated answer.